# My pd.DataFrame is stuck, how do I reset it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my code here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])
df.to_parquet(r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.parquet", engine='pyarrow', index=False)
df = pd.read_parquet(r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.parquet", engine='fastparquet')
```

Whenever I run it, I get the same output:

```
   key
0    1
```

It's not showing the contents of my parquet file. I tried pd.DataFrame.reset_index(), I tried deleting the dataframe and creating a new one, I tried df.reset_index(), I tried everything and the output is always the same. How do I reset what I did? I think the issue arose when I did this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])`

and now it seems like I can't go back. I even deleted my file and created a new one.

Comment: you cannot "go back", unless you saved the data explicitly somehow.

Comment: How are you running this code?  From the terminal, from an IDE or some other way?

Comment: i am using VScode. and running this locally. i dont understand what i did, why can't i get my data to show like it did before? how do i fix this?

Comment: so, if you have run the code above, `df = pd.DataFrame({'key': 1}, index=[0])` followed by `df.to_parquet(r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.parquet", engine='pyarrow', index=False)` writes precisely the dataframe you are reporting to disk. If you had another file at `C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.parquet` it was overwritten. You cannot go back.